# How to use default parameter value in a nested call?

Tags: php, function, arguments, default-value

I have this situation: function `a` (a class method, but it's not important, here...) invokes function `b`.
Function `a` has one parameter (say, `$p2`), with a *default* value.
Function `b` has one parameter (say, `$q2`), with a *default* value, too.

If function `a` is called **without** the parameter `$p2`, function `b` should be called **without** the parameter `$q2`, too, to force it using it's default value.
If function `a` is called **with** the parameter `$p2`, function `b` should be called **with** the parameter `$q2`.

To clearify with an example:

```
function a($p1, $p2 = "default value one") {
  if ($p2 === "default value") {
    b($p1);
  } else {
    b($p1, $p2);
  }
}

function b(q1, q2 = "default value two") {
  ...
}
```

Of course it's possible to use a test, as in the example above, but it looks me a really ugly solution... The question is:

Is there a better (faster, cleaner, smarter) code to implement this use case?

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this should be what you're looking for:

Just get all function arguments with [`func_get_args()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php), then simply call your next function with [`call_user_func_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php).

```
function a($p1, $p2 = "default value") {
    call_user_func_array("b", func_get_args());
}
```

Comment: Good. For sure this is someway *better*, but for the *cleaner* part (for example, code readability), I have some doubts... :-)

Comment: @MarcoS you asked for a *smarter* way, here you go :)

Comment: Ok, ok... +1 for you... But for the *faster* and *cleaner*?... +2 for me... :-)

Comment: @MarcoS For the faster one you might win it, because your method is twice as fast, but *cleaner*, I think the syntax is  maybe just unfamiliar for you. (So is your question answered or for what exactly are you looking for?)

Comment: I did already use `call_user_func_array()` and `func_get_args()` (though I didn't think to use it here...). The question is answered. Just waiting for something even *more* smart before accepting... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Function `a` default parameter must have same value as function `b` default parameter:

```
function a($p1, $p2 = null) {
    b($p1, $p2);
}

function b($p1, $p2 = null) {
    var_dump($p1, $p2);
}
```

So calling `a` with both parameters will pass these parameters to function `b`, while calling function `a` with only first parameter set will call `b` with passed first from user and second parameter as default value:

> a(2, 5); // --> (int)2 (int)5
>
> a(2); // --> (int)2 NULL

---

**[UPDATE]**

If functions can have different default values, than you need to detect default value:

```
function a($p1, $p2 = null) {
    $p2 = !is_null($p2) ? $p2 : 'defaultB';

    b($p1, $p2); // For string use `stricmp($p2, 'defaultA') !== 0`
}

function b($p1, $p2 = 'defaultB');
```

Comment: Sorry, it was not clear from my question, but default parameters for functions `a` and `b` *could* have different values.

Comment: In function `a` I don't know the value of 'defaultB'... :-(